# How to position a UIActivityIndicatorView in a UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I've this code for adding `UIActivityIndicatorView` to a `UITableViewCell`.

```
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    UIImage *spacer = [UIImage imageNamed:@"spacer"];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(220, 150));
    [spacer drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,spinner.frame.size.width,spinner.frame.size.height)];
    UIImage* resizedSpacer = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    cell.imageView.image = resizedSpacer;
    [cell.imageView addSubview:spinner];
    [spinner startAnimating];
```

Currently the image is shown in the top left of the 220x150 box. Instead I would like to put it in center. How can I do that? I've tried to change the two first parameters on `CGRectMake`, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've added `resizedSpacer` as the imageView without actually doing anything to `spinner`'s frame.  You want something like:

```
CGSize spinSize = spinner.frame.size;
spinner.frame = CGRectMake((220-spinSize.width)/2., (150-spinSize.height)/2.,spinSize.width, spinSize.height);
[cell.imageView addSubview:spinner];
```

I don't think that the logic involving `spacer` is required.  In fact, you may not even want to host the `UIActivityIndicatorView` in the `UIImageView` at all; why not position it directly within the tableview cell?